# Create a trigger to take the signintime and signouttime and put to hours worked for SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I'm trying to create a trigger to take the signintime and signouttime and put to hours worked.

I started with the code below, but its not quite working the way I want

```
BEGIN
declare @au_in char( 11 )
declare @au_out char( 11 )
declare @rowcount char( 11 )

set rowcount 0
select jargonf1_sqladmin.StaffRegisterV2.signInTime,jargonf1_sqladmin.StaffRegisterV2.signOutTime from jargonf1_sqladmin.StaffRegisterV2

set rowcount 1


while @rowcount <> 0
BEGIN
select @au_in = signInTime from jargonf1_sqladmin.StaffRegisterV2
select @au_out = signOutTime from jargonf1_sqladmin.StaffRegisterV2
DECLARE @Sign_In datetime

DECLARE @Sign_Out datetime

DECLARE @WorkedHours DECIMAL(18,2)

DECLARE @hours varchar(30)

DECLARE @minutes varchar(2)

DECLARE @seconds varchar(30)

set @Sign_In =  @au_in

set @Sign_Out = @au_out

set @seconds = abs(datediff(second, @Sign_In, @Sign_Out))

set @hours = @seconds / 3600

set @minutes = (@seconds - (@hours * 3600)) / 60

set @seconds = (@seconds - (@hours * 3600) - (@minutes * 60))

set @WorkedHours = @hours + '.' + @minutes 

SELECT @WorkedHours AS WorkedHours
set @rowcount = 2 + 1
END

set rowcount 0

END
```

Comment: "but its not quite working the way I want". Please add sample data and expected result. There's no way we can help you otherwise.

Comment: When writing a trigger, you should really refer to the `Inserted` and `Deleted` pseudo tables inside the trigger to find out what rows were affected (inserted, deleted, or updated).

Comment: I can add that trgger coding after this script works, its doesnt show the worked hours for each row, which is the problem only show to one row and also how to i save the result into the worked hours field?

Comment: It is time to take some steps back for multiple reasons. 2008 is unsupported - talk to your organization about that. Next, you need to have some level of proficiency in basic tsql before you try to write triggers. Almost all your variables are strings indicates you struggle with datatypes. Using "set rowcount 0" is sign that you struggle with set-based operations. So - start over and provide some sample data and the manual steps you take to compute the desired value. No code - just a written explanation.

Comment: ok so i made school boys errors, i read through my code again and got it to work. But if you were a good programmer you would have be able to fix my code, thanks SMor.

Answer (score 0):

Does this work at all? I see a couple of issues immediately:

First, you use `DECLARE @WorkedHours DECIMAL(18,2)`, but then you concatenate a string using `set @WorkedHours = @hours + '.' + @minutes`. This must result in an error `converting varchar to int`.

Second, your loop should never run more than once (I think this is the problem you are reporting) because you are using a constant: `set @rowcount = 2 + 1` when I think you want set`@rowcount = @rowcount + 1`. But then you need to test for the number of rows you want to convert.

Honestly, this procedure is something that I think you can do with a `SELECT` query that has a subquery to get the `datediff`, then just calculates the hours and minutes from the value returned by the subquery.

Answer (score 0):

ok I read through my code again, corrected school boy errors and got it to work, but can someone help with the line`SELECT @au_in,@au_out AS SignIN;`
 as I want to name the second column but it gives error like`SELECT @au_in,@au_out AS SignIN, SIGNOUT;`any ideas??